# What do you do with the wither rose?

Tags: minecraft-bedrock-edition

What is a wither rose? Besides a rare drop, I was wondering what it is useful for. Could it be used to make a wither skeleton farm? Just wondering. (BTW, I know how to get it. Please don’t answer with that).

Answer (score 6):

Wither Roses can be made into black dye (Which is ludicrously impractical in the early game unless you are in an old style world with zero potential squid spawning zones, in which case you may be better off with a new world) and used for semi-automatic mob farms, as mentioned by Zyxilef. But, they can also be used for traps, and can be used to make suspicious stew that gives the Wither effect. Also, to answer your second question, you cannot use it to make a Wither Skeleton farm. Wither Skeletons are immune to the Wither effect. They can also just be a cool decoration, a trophy item, or a flex that you're rich enough to have them.

Comment: It may be valid on Bedrock, but on Java it's quite the opposite. Wither rose farms (using caged Wither) tend to be significantly more efficient than squid farms, becoming a great source of black dye. Wither rose covered floor in fortesss crossing bounding box will only spawn wither skeletons making an excellent wither skeleton farm, and they are a good killing floor cover for full auto mob farms (planted on soulsand through which hoppers can pull drops).

Comment: @SF. that is valid only late game, I am not saying it's not valid but clarifying that squid are better early game.

Answer (score 0):

The wither rose is dropped when a mob is killed by the wither. Besides being able to be crafted into black die and potentially being used for a semi-automatic mob farm, I can’t think of any uses. However, there is also potential for an iron farm involving iron golems. (I will note that this is extremely impractical as wither roses are a very rare drop and there are much easier ways to make above items.)

Answer (score 0):

Wither Roses can be used to create black dye. It can also be used as an ingredient in creating suspicious stew, but it will give the stew the wither effect when consumed. It can also be used as a defense if placed strategically. It can be also used in Magma Cube farms to kill the Magma cubes. Any player or mob that touches it will be granted the wither effect, a status effect similar to poison. This is the same status effect inflicted by Wither skeletons and Withers. They are good in traps as the wither effect helps in killing enemies and allies alike. They are also used in many auto-killer farms.